# MySQL Query - produce array within result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to, in **one** query select orders and have their items attached to them (right now I'm selecting the orders, then using a separate query selecting the order_items - this is proving very slow on a large amount of orders...

**orders**: id | name | total

**order_items**: id | order_id | price | qty

**order_items_info**: id | order_id | order_item_id | tracking_no

The last thing I want to do is: add my **order_items_info** table to the item array.

```
$orders = array(
    array(
        'id' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'items' => array(
            array(
                'order_item_id' => '',
                'price' => '',
                'qty' => '',
                'item_info' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'order_item_id' => '',
                'price' => '',
                'qty' => '',
                'item_info' => array()
            ),
            ...
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: What's wrong with JOIN?

Comment: Your order_items table needs an item_id field that joins to your item table.

Comment: It has one, but it made it a bit complicated so I left it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT o.id,name,total,item_info,price,qty FROM orders o 
JOIN order_items oi ON o.id=oi.order_id
JOIN order_items_info oii ON oii.order_id=o.id
AND oii.order_item_id=oi.id
```

Just a wild guess until you post your table info.

Comment: I forgot to add the 2nd part of the question: adding order_items_info to the items array?

Comment: I dont see anything order_items_info anywhere in your tables.

Comment: Sorry, it was a bit confusing. I've updated it to make a little more sense.

Answer (score 0):

> select * from orders join order_items on (orders.id = order_id)